# ODBC Connection Error using Stored Procedure in Netbeans

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

I am making an inventory management program. The Problem is I am using multiple SQL queries with stored procedure. Which is something like this:

```
try
{

    CallableStatement c= m.XC.prepareCall("{call addCategory_Combobox}");
    ResultSet rs = c.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next())
    {
        String name = rs.getString("category");
        jComboBox2.addItem(name);
    }
    rs.close();
    c.close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.out.println(ex.toString());
}
```

Here is connection I have made so far:

```
public class MyConnection
{
    Connection XC;Statement ST;
    public MyConnection()
    {

        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            XC=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:signupcon", "sa", "123");
            ST=XC.createStatement();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I run the code for the 1st time, it executes successfully. But when I run the same code for the second time. it get the following Error:`java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Connection is busy with results for another hstmt`

and here is the SQL Query Code:

```
create proc addCategory_Combobox
    as 
  begin
    Declare @Status varchar(max)
    select category from Category
    SELECT @Status as result 
  end
go
```

Comment: Open and close the connection for every call.

Comment: your MyConnection creates a Statement and then you make a createStatement again in the code above. And your code is really painful for my eyes, why using big letters ?? ... I think you want to create a MyConnection first, and then a createStatement. But your MyConnection is just a class, which doesnt extends Connection. And also you don't have a method that returns a Connection. You simple use the XC.. please check some simple demos.. like http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/SimpleexampleofJDBCODBCfunctionality.htm

Comment: I did open and close(). but nothing happens.....

Comment: Let me try Mr. SimpleMind...Will inform you..

Comment: it is not the close issue here, Joop ment as a good practice is to open and close. But your case is special ;) .. as you make a connection, and stmnt and then a stmnt again with the same connection etc.

Comment: The flow should be, make a connection, a stmnt, execute, get results, close. Get happy!

Comment: as you can see Statement st1 is not being used.....forgot to remove it.